# C# generate code from interface

Tags: c#, interface, code-generation

I have an `interface` definition in `C#.` Is there any tool to auto-create (generate) all the empty methods of that interface with a default return type? 
For example i already have:

```
interface ISampleInterface
{
    void SampleMethod();
    int func(int);
}
```

and i want:

```
// auto interface member implementation:
class ImplementationClass : ISampleInterface
{

    void ISampleInterface.SampleMethod()
    {

        return;
    }

    // changed return type to int according to interface definintion
    int ISampleInterface.func(int a)
    {

        return a;
    }

}
```

Comment: consider "Re-sharper" tool.

Comment: VisualStudio does same without Resharper too.

Comment: @PranavSingh only some versions of Visual Studio

Comment: @verdesrobert Ohh, I don't knew that I used premium, professional & ultimate all have it. Probably express don't have it.

Comment: @PranavSingh exactly :D some Express versions have very very less features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just right click on your `class ImplementationClass : ISampleInterface` and click on `Implement Interface`

or else you may consider to use [Re-sharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) tool

Comment: Only available with specific versions of Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can (standard) implement all the interfaces using ReSharper

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp50/Code_Generation__Implementing_Overriding_Methods.html